# How do I split an input string in Java?

Tags: java, string, split, trim

User enters a string in java, I have to split it into different components.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String test = scanner.next();

// split the test variable using the split method
String [] parts = test.split(" ,", 3);

s[i].setFirstName(parts[0].trim());
s[i].setlastName(parts[1].trim());
s[i].setID(Integer.parseInt(parts[2].trim()));
s[i].setgrade(Integer.parseInt(parts[3].trim()));
```

but it's not working. I can only get the first word to show up.

Comment: What is not working? Is there an error message? Expand a little.

Comment: Mention your sample input

Comment: May be because of `scanner.next();` with space. use `scanner.nextLine();`.

Comment: I can get only one word to show up.  it doesn't read any proceeding words.  I also get an Array index out of bounds error.  Using scanner.next(); gives an array index out of bounds error.

Comment: You're using 4 parts but request at most 3 parts. And you can't be sure you always get 4 parts (for instance for `test = "foo, bar"`).

Answer (score 0):

Use `nextLine()` rather than `next()` should fix the issue.

For further reference, take a look at [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Answer (score 0):

With your comment

> I can get only one word to show up. it doesn't read any proceeding
>   words.

Use `nextLine()` instead of `next()`.

`next()` will only return what comes before a space.

`nextLine()` automatically moves the scanner down after returning the current line.

```
name = scanner.nextLine();
```

[Scanner doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: The input has to be entered in one line.  firstname, lastname, ID, grade  not on a new line

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
String test = scanner.next();
```

to

```
String test = scanner.nextLine();
```

`scanner.next()` takes a word upto it encounters a blank space. `nextLine()` will consider the whole line.